# Linux environment variable is not accessible in bash script run by supervisor

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, supervisord

OS: ubuntu 14.x
Environment variable is defined at /etc/environment

export `MY_VAR="Fom Xong"`

**my_bash.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo "My_VAR Value: $MY_VAR"
```

if the I run the script using `./my_bash` it works perfectly.

But if given in supervisor it dont work

```
command = /var/www/myapp/web/bash/my_bash.sh
```

Any clue?

Comment: `/etc/environment` isn't a shell script; drop the word `export`.

Comment: @chepner, didnt work that

Comment: just in case: https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/

Comment: The */etc/environment* file is read by the Linux pam_env module. If your "supervisor" (whatever that is) does not use PAM or is not started via a mechanism that uses PAM then that config file won't be read. The person who wrote the pam_env module recognized that people might be inclined to put lines like `export var=val` rather than just `var=val` in that file and silently ignore the unnecessary `export`. Note that the equivalent `typeset -x var=val` will be completely ignored; only `export` is special-cased.